# Graylog2 Server unable to connect to ElasticSearch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, graylog2

I'm trying to install GrayLog2 on my Ubuntu server to manage all logs from multiple location.

I have install Mongodb, Java and Elastic Search but it failed to detect the elastic search when I run

`sudo java -jar /opt/graylog2-server/graylog2-server.jar --debug`

Error from graylog

```
2014-12-11 03:29:23,700 INFO : org.elasticsearch.transport - [graylog2-server] bound_address   {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9350]}, publish_address {inet[/10.175.112.147:9350]}
2014-12-11 03:29:26,739 WARN : org.elasticsearch.discovery - [graylog2-server] waited for 3s and no initial state was set by the discovery
2014-12-11 03:29:26,739 INFO : org.elasticsearch.discovery - [graylog2-server] graylog2/MNpZ3HLXRbaKkpw--872Mw
2014-12-11 03:29:26,739 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.gateway - [graylog2-server] can't wait on start for (possibly) reading state from gateway, will do it asynchronously
2014-12-11 03:29:26,740 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] started
2014-12-11 03:29:26,886 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
2014-12-11 03:29:29,897 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
2014-12-11 03:29:31,783 ERROR: org.graylog2.Main -
ERROR: Could not successfully connect to ElasticSearch. Check that your cluster state is not RED and that ElasticSearch is running properly.
```

**More infomation**
ElasticSearch Health Status
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true`

```
{
"cluster_name" : "graylog2",
"status" : "green",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
"active_primary_shards" : 0,
"active_shards" : 0,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

Graylog2Server Version: 0.20.2
ElasticSearch Version: 0.90.0

Thanks